# AWS ELB Health Checks store logs from my EC2 node where unavailable application was detected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm using custom path(my application health check url) configuration with ELB Health Checks.

Is any way to store logs(from different folders on disk) to some external store(for example S3 Bucket) from my EC2 node where unavailable application was detected before ELB decided to create a new instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/lifecycle-hooks.html) to perform some action on the instance before it is terminated. In my opinion this is probably more complicated than what you need.

I would recommend simply setting up [AWS CloudWatch Log streaming](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) on all your instances, so that all your logs are archived and available even after the instance is terminated. Alternatively you could setup something similar using third-party logging services like [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/) or [Logentries](https://logentries.com/).